# Structured light, infinite focus

Tags: optics, visible-light

Im interested in projecting a static image across a room that stays focused over a wide range of distances from the projector, without re-adjustment, for a structured light setup.

ie, the target may move anywhere from a couple feet to 10 feet from the projector.

Is such a thing possible?  How/is this achieved in practice?

Comment: The easy approach to this is just to stop the lens in the projector right down.  Unfortunately this means the image will be rather dim.

Comment: Use a laser scanner. That's typically the equipment for something like this, isn't it?

Comment: Typically laser scanners yes, but attempting to build an alternative setup with a bare minimum of parts / complexity.

Comment: Also, Ive seen several setups with regular projectors, so curious what depth range they cover.

Answer (score 0):

> ... projecting a static image across a room that stays focused over a wide range of distances from the projector, ...

A [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) is created and mapped to the 2D surfaces in the room. To record the view and show it to others you simply track the position of the camera.

Here is a **before** view of this person's room:

[image: Empty Room with a TV, Table and Couch]

Here is the room with fake wall texture and additional objects:

[image: Before View - Ordinary Room]

Here is a screenshot from part 3 of the PlayStation video listed below:

[image: After View - 3D Projection]

In another part his room becomes flooded and he is attacked by a sea monster:

[image: Arrggh, sea monster]

That movie was created with a room, a RED camera, two PlayStation Move controllers, a computer, the Sony PlayStation SDK, and a film crew. The room is at least 12' x 12'.

There is relatively simple hardware available that can be assembled and controlled to produce a 3D projection mapping on the 2D surfaces in your room, it's not simple to do.

- Microsoft explains their prototype IllumiRoom in their video: "[IllumiRoom by Microsoft Research: Peripheral Projected Illusions for Interactive Experiences](https://youtu.be/L2w-XqW7bF4)" which uses a wide field projector and Microsoft's Kinect sensor. It is documented on their webpage: "[IllumiRoom: Peripheral Projected Illusions for Interactive Experiences](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/illumiroom-peripheral-projected-illusions-for-interactive-experiences/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fillumiroom%2F)" and includes a paper: "[IllumiRoom: Peripheral Projected Illusions for Interactive Experiences](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/illumiroom-peripheral-projected-illusions-for-interactive-experiences/)" (7.6 MB .[PDF](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/illumiroom-illumiroom_chi2013_bjones.pdf)).
- For the PlayStation advertisement "Great Films Fill Rooms" they attached the [PlayStation Move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Move) controller to a camera. That permitted mixing real-time projection mapping with head tracking and camera tracking (both at once) for a sort of live match-moving-like effect. Here is the result:

  - "[Most Insane Immersive Movie Experience EVER - Part 1](https://youtu.be/VrgWH1KUDt4)"
  - "[Most Insane Immersive Movie Experience EVER - Part 2](https://youtu.be/N_cKsOe7hLI)"
  - "[Most Insane Immersive Movie Experience EVER - Part 3](https://youtu.be/HQ1KaYEBe5U)"
  - "[The Most Immersive Movie Experience EVER -- Making Of Version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLBMghIJM5Q)"
- In the article: "[Projecting 3D Objects in Mid-Air](http://projection-mapping.org/projecting-3d-objects-mid-air/)" researchers at [Burton Inc](http://burton-jp.com/en/index.htm) explain using a laser outdoors to ionize the air and create a 3D projection mid-air without a screen. It is demonstrated in their video: "[Aerial Burton 3D display projects images into mid-air #DigInfo](https://youtu.be/GNoOiXkXmYQ)".
- In the videos: "[Pmomo: Projection Mapping on Movable 3D Object](https://youtu.be/oauJ99Mfru4)", the accompanying article: "[Pmomo: Projection Mapping on Movable 3D Object](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2858036.2858329)" **and** another video: "[Projection Mapping": Experimental Projector Shoots Steady Images On Moving Objects](https://youtu.be/x_u5pliamo8)", and it's accompanying article: "[Experimental Projector Shoots Steady Images Even On Moving Objects](https://www.geek.com/tech/experimental-projector-shoots-steady-images-even-on-moving-objects-1675892/?source)" the authors demonstrate 3D projection mapping on movable objects.

Comment: This is a primer on projection mapping, but my question was on specific details of focus over a large dynamic area. Cheers

Comment: This answer deals with your question asking for a "yes" or "no" answer and provides an outline of a few of the many methods. What is your budget?

Comment: Unfortunately none of those links cover a wide depth range as requested, but instead focus on perspective correction issues, not focal issues.
Cheers.

Comment: Cheers it is [correct](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).